# Detect conflicts before merging files that will cause conflicts in the future

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

### Prerequisite

- Developing the same repository with multiple (3 ~ 5) developers
- Each developer works on a different branch. When work is finished, it is merged into the `main` branch.

### What is the problem?

If you are working on a large project, you will be working on the same branch for a long time without merging into `main`. This increases the risk of conflicts. We want to be aware of the risk of conflicts as soon as possible.

What kind of method do you think is best? I would like to know if there is already a script or tool to perform this task.

### What I tried

Frequently merging `main` into a working branch is not much of a solution, since it does not necessarily mean that someone else's work has been merged into `main`.

We want to know if a conflict will occur when another developer's branch is pushed.

Comment: The fear of conflicts is much overrated. There is no "risk" in conflicts. Given the tasks that the developers have to complete, you cannot avoid conflicts. You can only shift the responsibility who has to (or is able to) resolve the conflicts around. Do not fear conflicts. They are normal things to happen during development. Learn how to deal with conflicts and how to resolve them. Then there is no problem to be solved.

Comment: We want to know as soon as possible that a conflict will occur.

Comment: How long-lasting are these branches? Around 2-4 weeks would be reasonable. Developers are good at dividing up problems into their lower-level components. Instead of one big new thing, there is certainly a way to merge more frequently and only activate the new feature when it is completed. How about comparing the other branches to each other? That won't prove conflicts to main, but could help. Also comparing all dev branches against each other takes extra time that you can spend resolving conflicts. Try this: `git diff –color-words my-branch .. other-branch`

Comment: *We want to know as soon as possible that a conflict will occur.* And then what? The conflict is there. It is unavoidable. Somebody *has* to resolve it. Unless, of course, one side throws away their work and comes up with a completely different solution for their task.

Comment: Just fetch and merge (`git pull origin main --no-ff`) when you want to know if there would be any conflicts at that moment. If conflicts occur, use `git merge --abort` to end the merge. If it succeeds without conflicts, use `git reset HEAD^ --hard` to return to the head before the merge.

Comment: One way to avoid conflicts is to avoid long-lived branches. One way to do it is to follow "work on trunk" methodology, where each developer works either directly on the main branch, or at least merges to the main branch very frequently. This has some benefits (the new code is frequently tested by the CI/CD loop, no big-bang merge needed) and when used with feature toggles it can be adopted without major problems.